# What's the overhead for gen_server calls in Erlang/OTP?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp

This [post](http://ninenines.eu/articles/erlang-scalability/) on Erlang scalability says there's an overhead for every call, cast or message to a gen_server. How much overhead is it, and what is it for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cost that is being referenced is the cost of a (relatively blind) function call to an *external module*. This happens because everything in the gen_* abstractions are callbacks to externally defined functions (the functions you write in your callback module), and not function calls that can be optimized by the compiler within a single module. A part of that cost is the resolution of the call (finding the right code to execute -- the same reason each "dot" in.a.long.function.or.method.call in Python or Java raise the cost of resolution) and another part of the cost is the actual call itself.

**BUT**

This is not something you can calculate as a simple quantity and then multiply by to get a meaningful answer regarding the cost of operations across your system.

There are too many variables, points of constraint, and unexpectedly cheap elements in a massively concurrent system like Erlang where the hardest parts of concurrency are abstracted away (scheduling related issues) and the most expensive elements of parallel processing are made extremely cheap (context switching, process spawn/kill and process:memory ratio).

The only way to really know anything about a massively concurrent system, which by its very nature will exhibit *emergent* behavior, is to write one and measure it in actual operation. You could write exactly the same program in pure Erlang once and then again as an OTP application using gen_* abstractions and measure the difference in performance that way -- but the benchmark numbers would only mean anything *to that particular program* and probably only mean anything *under that particular load profile*.

All this taken in mind... the numbers that really matter when we start splitting hairs in the Erlang world are the reduction budget costs the scheduler [takes into account](http://jlouisramblings.blogspot.jp/2013/01/how-erlang-does-scheduling.html). Lukas Larsson at Erlang Solutions put out a video a while back about the scheduler and details the way these costs impact the system, what they are, and how to tweak the values under certain circumstances ([Understanding the Erlang Scheduler](https://vimeo.com/86106434)). Aside from external resources (iops delay, network problems, NIF madness, etc.) that have nothing to do with Erlang/OTP the overwhelming factor is [the behavior of the scheduler](http://www.erlang.se/workshop/2002/Sanchez.pdf), not the "cost of a function call".

In all cases, though, the only way to really know is to write a prototype that represents the basic behavior you expect in your actual system and test it.

Comment: It's not just calls to external modules that create overhead -- interactions with `gen_server` and other OTP behaviors normally involve messages between processes. For example, a `gen_server:cast/2` sends a message from the caller to the `gen_server` process, and a `gen_server:call/3` means a message to the `gen_server` followed by a reply message back to the calling process. A `gen_server:call/3` also sets up a monitor of the `gen_server` process so that if it dies, the caller doesn't hang waiting for a reply that will never arrive.

Comment: @SteveVinoski Indeed. But the messaging and link overhead would exist whether this were an OTP behavior or not -- the unique thing is the external call, particularly in the context of the post that was linked. (The post indicates custom process code can be written to have less overhead than OTP behaviors.) Well, I suppose one could write a sync call without linking, but that's inviting even larger (and weirder) problems.